# Entity Framework: How to configure a relationship with foreign key not in database?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have some relationships are base on properties not in database, as below example, the foreign key `BrandID` is extracted from `ProdID`, is it possible to configure this kind of relationships with annotations or fluent API?

```
public partial class Prod
{
    public string ProdID { get; set; }
    public string BrandID { get { return ProdID.Split('-')[0]; } }     
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}

public class Brand
{
    public string BrandID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Prod> Prods { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to know how EF manage relationships. Using data annotation or FluentAPI you creating relationships beetwen entities. Exactly what you want to achieve? You want relationship one-to-many beetwen `Prod` and `Brand`?

Comment: Not with this property. EF won't be able to use `Prod.BrandID` because it can't be a mapped property.

Comment: @ M. Wiśnicki, Yes, I want to config one-to-many relationship between `Prod` and `Brand`.